# How to use f2py without the full file directory

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have been using f2py for a while now on windows 10 but i have to type in the full file directory to access it eg: `C:\..\...\Python36\Scripts\f2py.py` and it is just getting a bit annoying. Does anyone know how to add this to path or something so I just have to use f2py.py to use the script?

Comment: If the python.exe from Python36 is on your PATH, then the same Python36\Scripts should also be on your PATH. If it's not, you have to edit your PATH environment variable. On Windows, default environment variables (both system and users) are buried in the System Control Panel, but Microsoft keeps renaming that control panel, and changing the way to find it, with each version; if you can't find it, search on, or ask on, Super User, and you should get an answer easily.

Comment: Also, once you change it in the Control Panel, you'll need to open a new Command Prompt windows before it takes effect.

Comment: One last thing: If you installed Python using an installer from python.org, or using Anaconda, they should both have given you the option to modify the PATH at install time. If you said no to that, re-running the installer may let you re-do that choice without having to uninstall and reinstall everything… but no promises; I haven't installed on Windows in a few years…

Comment: so just add the scripts folder to the path?

Comment: Yes. If `C:\…\Python36\Scripts\f2py.py` works, then, once you add that Scripts directory to the PATH, `f2py.py` should work the same way.

Comment: I just did that and it still doesnt work?